# font-face doesn't work in IE10

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, internet-explorer-10

I've absolutly no idea how to display the clarendon and kievit font on IE10.. When I refresh the webpage it starts with the clarendon font but then turns to another..

this is the part of my code with the @font-face :

```
@font-face {

    font-family: 'clarendonregular';
    src: url('fonts/clarendo-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/clarendo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/clarendo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/clarendo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/clarendo-webfont.svg#clarendonregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Which Clarendon are you using, how did you produce the font files, what does the HTML look like, do you have scripting, etc. In a word, please demonstrate a testable case. Just saying “foobar does not work” is not a well-defined problem, for most values of foobar.

Comment: i've used the font-face generator for everything..

Comment: Any update on a fix for this issue? i'm seeing the same behaviour in IE10. Basically, the page renders okay, then on refresh the font reverts to a serif style font.

Answer (score 0):

Dou you try webfont generator ? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator